# Laravel creates multiple sessions for the same user logs him out

Tags: php, laravel, session

When I log into my Laravel 5 application, almost every time I click a link inside the application, I get logged out and redirected to the login screen.

Now, when I check the framework/sessions folder while running, I see that it is not generating only one session file, but somewhat randomly it generates a new session file, logging the me out or giving me a TokenMismatch exception.

Any ideas of what it might be and how I could debug this?

Comment: check `config.sessions`: `lifetime` and `expire_on_close`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this was caused by Laravel attempting to write to the `storage/framework/sessions` directory. I thought I had already covered read/write permissions for the storage directory but apparently when using the "file" session driver it's best to check you still have R/W permissions in order to make new session files.

To that extent, I switched on Redis, ran `composer require predis/predis`, changed the session driver in my `.env` file to `redis` and I've never had a problem with Laravel session storage since.

You can also use the `database` driver if you don't feel like using Redis.